# Пагинация для данных из разных источников

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Добрый Вечер.

Делаю пагинацию для одной сущности. Если ее делать для данных из одной базы, то проблем никаких нет: взял все подходящие данные, задал страничку пагинации и кольво элементов. Легко. Но мне нужно брать часть данных из внешнего приложения. И в таком случае делать пагинацию в sql запросе не вариант. Была идея в самом начале получать данные из внешнего приложения, затем записывать из в базу во временную табличку, а за тем уже делать выборку по двум таблицам одной базы, и спокойно пагинировать полный набор данных, и в конце удалять временную табличку. Но если делать все эти манипуляции в одной транзакции, то данные, которые пришли из вне, запишутся в базу только в конце всей транзакции, и соответственно учесть их в общем запросе не выйдет. А если делать это в разных транзакциях, то это вроде как не правильно, с точки зрения того что если после отработки записи внешних данных во временную табличку условно выключится свет, то мало того что вся логика не отработает, еще и мусор в базе висеть останется.

Если кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей, подскажите пожалуйста как ее обычно правильно решать. В проекте использую Spring и Hibernate с дефолтными sql запросами.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь отдельный поток Thread для запроса данных с внешнего приложения и объект Future для него. Запрашиваешь данные из внутренней базы. Когда придут данные, достаешь их из объекта Future. Объединяешь данные. Отдаешь данные.
Еще можно распилить объект на две сущности. И потом собирать из него объект DTO.
Посмотри паттерн DTO.